# TerminateThread function call is not working as expected

Tags: c++, windows

I am creating a thread using `CreateThread(&sa, 16*1024*1024, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)listener_thread,(void *) this, 0, &threadID)`. The thread is created without any problem. The problem comes up when I try to terminate the above created thread with:

```
 TerminateThread(thread,dwExitCode);
 DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
 printf(errorCode);
```

`TerminateThread` call is unsuccessfull with errorCode being printed as 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`). Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: You should really check the return value from `TerminateThread` before printing the error code. The reason is that not all functions clear the error code when they succeed.

Comment: I googled a lot on this. Do I have to set SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES as first parapeter while creating thread. But how to set THREAD_ALL_ACCESS at thread creation time?

Comment: Double-check that the thread handle you're giving to TerminateThread is the one that was returned from CreateThread.  Oh, and check that the thread hasn't already exited.  Permissions shouldn't be a problem, but to eliminate that possibility, pass NULL for the first argument to get the default security descriptor.